# Show pages link in a nav side bar

Tags: reactjs, routes, sidebar

I am stuck in a problem . I have a table in which I show some startup names as a link. It has a home page, product page, and so on. My task is that when I click one of the given startups then the home and product page of that startup will appear on the nav sidebar. I used Routing v6

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  useLocation,
} from 'react-router-dom';
// import { Link as RouterLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  // Avatar,
  Box,
  // Divider,
  Drawer,
  Hidden,
  List,
  // Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';
import {
  AlertCircle as AlertCircleIcon,
  BarChart as BarChartIcon,
  Lock as LockIcon,
  Settings as SettingsIcon,
  ShoppingBag as ShoppingBagIcon,
  User as UserIcon,
  UserPlus as UserPlusIcon,
  Users as UsersIcon
} from 'react-feather';
import NavItem from './NavItem';
// import AutoX from './AutoX';

// const user = {
//   avatar: '/static/images/avatars/avatar_6.png',
//   jobTitle: 'Senior Developer',
//   name: 'Katarina Smith',
// };

const items = [
  {
    href: '/app/dashboard',
    icon: BarChartIcon,
    title: 'Dashboard',
  },
  {
    href: '/app/customers',
    icon: UsersIcon,
    title: 'Customer'
  },
  {
    href: '/app/products',
    icon: ShoppingBagIcon,
    title: 'Products'
  },
  {
    href: '/app/account',
    icon: UserIcon,
    title: 'Account'
  },
  {
    href: '/app/settings',
    icon: SettingsIcon,
    title: 'Settings'
  },
  {
    href: '/login',
    icon: LockIcon,
    title: 'Login'
  },
  {
    href: '/register',
    icon: UserPlusIcon,
    title: 'Register'
  },
  {
    href: '/404',
    icon: AlertCircleIcon,
    title: 'Error'
  }
];
const autox = [
  {
    href: '/startup/autox',
    icon: BarChartIcon,
    title: '',
  },
];

const DashboardSidebar = ({ onMobileClose, openMobile }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (openMobile && onMobileClose) {
      onMobileClose();
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

  const content = (
    <Box
      style={{ backgroundColor: '#2C394B' }}
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        height: '100%',
      }}
    >
      <Box sx={{ p: 2 }}>
        <List>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <NavItem
              href={item.href}
              key={item.title}
              title={item.title}
              icon={item.icon}
            />
          ))}
        </List>
        <List>
          {autox.map((at) => (
            <NavItem
              href={at.href}
              key={at.title}
              title={at.title}
              icon={at.icon}
            />
          ))}
        </List>
        {/* <List>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/startup/autox" element={<AutoX />} />
          </Routes>
        </List> */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Hidden lgUp>
        <Drawer
          anchor="left"
          onClose={onMobileClose}
          open={openMobile}
          variant="temporary"
          PaperProps={{
            sx: {
              width: 256
            }
          }}
        >
          {content}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden xlDown>
        <Drawer
          anchor="left"
          open
          variant="persistent"
          PaperProps={{
            sx: {
              width: 256,
              top: 64,
              height: 'calc(100% - 64px)'
            }
          }}
        >
          {content}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
    </>
  );
};

DashboardSidebar.propTypes = {
  onMobileClose: PropTypes.func,
  openMobile: PropTypes.bool
};

DashboardSidebar.defaultProps = {
  onMobileClose: () => {
  },
  openMobile: false
};

export default DashboardSidebar;
```

this is the coding of the sidebar and autox is one of the startup.

Comment: Share the `NavItem` component, please.

Comment: sir how can i share the nav item component in commentts